# twitter bootstrap carousel not working properly ( symfony2 project )

Tags: javascript, symfony, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

when loading the page , my console says:

```
                $('.carousel').carousel is not a function
```

the generated html source code (i use symfony & twig files) look like this :

```
<body>        

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
           <div class="span6 well">
                 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
                       <!-- Carousel items -->
                         <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="active item"><img alt="" src="/projet_etienne_auth/web/bundles/etiennepsav/images/carousel1.jpg"></div>
                                    <div class="item"><img alt="" src="/projet_etienne_auth/web/bundles/etiennepsav/images/carousel2.jpg"></div>
                         </div>
                        <!-- Carousel nav -->
                        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                       <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>  


<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->  

    <script rel="javascript" href="/projet_etienne_auth/web/bundles/etiennepsav/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript" media="all" ></script>
    <script rel="javascript" href="/projet_etienne_auth/web/bundles/etiennepsav/js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript" media="all" ></script>  
    <script rel="javascript" href="/projet_etienne_auth/web/bundles/etiennepsav/js/bootstrap-carousel.js" type="text/javascript" media="all" ></script> 
    <script rel="javascript" href="/projet_etienne_auth/web/bundles/etiennepsav/js/bootstrap-transition.js" type="text/javascript" media="all" ></script> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.carousel').carousel()  ;
 });

       </script>
```

Would anyone spot what's wrong?
cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change your javascript at the end to the following..

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script rel="javascript" href="/projet_etienne_auth/web/bundles/etiennepsav/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript" media="all" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel();
});
</script>
```

the jquery library needs to be the first script file included, then the bootstrap.js file.

Only include the following script files if you didnt include them all within the bootstrap download package..

```
<script rel="javascript" href="/projet_etienne_auth/web/bundles/etiennepsav/js/bootstrap-transition.js" type="text/javascript" media="all" ></script> 
<script rel="javascript" href="/projet_etienne_auth/web/bundles/etiennepsav/js/bootstrap-carousel.js" type="text/javascript" media="all" ></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a double entry to your jquery libraries.

Also, move the jquery.min or jquery-1.8.3 to the first line (and remove one of them too, because they are essentially the same).

Answer (score 0):

at the end i have downloaded again boostrap.js including the carousel at

```
     http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html
```

put in my html head like this

```
          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script rel="javascript" href="{{ asset('bundles/etiennepsav/js/bootstrap.js') }}" type="text/javascript" media="all" ></script>


          <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('.carousel').carousel();
                                           });
           </script>
```

i have deleted the whole web folder from my symfony projet

then reloaded it using the console command

```
      php app/console assets:install web
```